# difference between detectObjectOnImage and runModelonImage in tflite flutter

Tags: flutter, adb, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to make a tflite multiple object detector in flutter
I came across two function which takes image path as input that's why this question.

the two function are `detectObjectOnImage` and `runModelOnImage` and when I use `runModelOnImage` my code is running and if I swap it with `detectObjectOnImage` the interprter does initialize but on calling the function the app automatically closes and shows `Lost connection to device`

this is how my code goes

```
classifyImage(String imgpath) async {
    var output = await Tflite.runModelOnImage(
        path: imgpath,
        imageMean: 0.0,
        imageStd: 255.0,
        threshold: 0.2,
        numResults: 1,
        asynch: true,
    );
    setState(() {
      _loading = false;
      outputs = output;
    });
    print(outputs);
    print(outputs[0]["label"]);
  }
```

I guess my assumptions are correct but I don't know why its not working, apart from that I created a model from Teachable machine by google and it only detects one object at a time so my next question is how do I make it detect more than 1 object

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two functions are their usages:

For object detection you use Tflite.detectObjectOnImage()

For image classification (finding objects without printing boxes around them) you use Tflite.runModelOnImage()

The two Methods return different sized tensors. When the Tensors can't be mapped to the expected output the app disconnects as you described it.

---

Regarding your second Question:

You set the parameter numResults, which limits the number of results, to 1. Increase this number to get more results.
(source: https://pub.dev/packages/tflite#Example)